# pycord dropdown menu - multiple selection if statement

Tags: discord, dropdown, pycord

The title Probably makes it confusing but let me clarify what my question is
So pretty much I have a dropdown menu where the user will select two of the colors, I don't understand how I can make it so if someone for example was the select Yellow and Red Circle it would respond with a GIF of that selection - It would do the same thing with each combination...

```
class mix(discord.ui.View):
    @discord.ui.select( # the decorator that lets you specify the properties of the select menu
        placeholder = "Choose a potion", # the placeholder text that will be displayed if nothing is selected
        min_values = 2, # the minimum number of values that must be selected by the users
        max_values = 2, # the maximum number of values that can be selected by the users
        options = [ # the list of options from which users can choose, a required field
            discord.SelectOption(
                label="",
                value='1'
            ),
            discord.SelectOption(
                label="",
                value='2'
            ),
            discord.SelectOption(
                label="",
                value='3'
            ),
            discord.SelectOption(
                label="",
                value='4'
            ),
            discord.SelectOption(
                label="",
                value='5'
            ),
        ]
    )
    async def select_callback(self, select, interaction): # the function called when the user is done selecting options
        if select.value == "" and "":
            await interaction.response.send_message("https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/957163963588681788/957164412807036928/yg.gif")
        elif select.value[0] == "" and "":
            await interaction.response.send_message("https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/957163963588681788/957166502258286592/yc.gif")
```

````
async def button(ctx):
    embed=discord.Embed(title=f"Choose Wisely!", description="",color=0x660066)
    embed.set_image(url="https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/999932873077424128/1047271785298657310/unknown.png?width=459&height=586")
    await ctx.respond(embed=embed, view=mix()) # Send a message with our View class that contains the button```

Any help would be apricated <3
````

Answer (score 0):

Figures it out! - Here for anyone that might need this

```
    @discord.ui.select( # the decorator that lets you specify the properties of the select menu
        placeholder = "Choose a potion", # the placeholder text that will be displayed if nothing is selected
        min_values = 1, # the minimum number of values that must be selected by the users
        max_values = 2, # the maximum number of values that can be selected by the users
        options = [ # the list of options from which users can choose, a required field
            discord.SelectOption(
                label="",
                value='1'
            ),
            discord.SelectOption(
                label="",
                value='2'
            ),
            discord.SelectOption(
                label="",
                value='3'
            ),
            discord.SelectOption(
                label="",
                value='4'
            ),
            discord.SelectOption(
                label="",
                value='5'
            ),
        ]
    )
    async def select_callback(self, select, interaction): # the function called when the user is done selecting options
        if select.values[0] == "1" and "2":
            await interaction.response.send_message("https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/957163963588681788/957164412807036928/yg.gif")
        if select.values[0] == "2" and "1":
            await interaction.response.send_message("https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/957163963588681788/957164412807036928/yg.gif")

        if select.values[0] == "1" and "3":
            await interaction.response.send_message("https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/957163963588681788/957166502258286592/yc.gif")
        if select.values[0] == "3" and "1":
            await interaction.response.send_message("https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/957163963588681788/957166502258286592/yc.gif")

        if select.values[0] == "1" and "4":
            await interaction.response.send_message("https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/957163963588681788/957165125381533746/yp.gif")
        if select.values[0] == "4" and "1":
            await interaction.response.send_message("https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/957163963588681788/957165125381533746/yp.gif")


        if select.values[0] == "1" and "5":
            await interaction.response.send_message("https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/957163963588681788/957165284152717322/yb.gif")
        if select.values[0] == "5" and "1":
            await interaction.response.send_message("https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/957163963588681788/957165284152717322/yb.gif")


        if select.values[0] == "2" and "3":
            await interaction.response.send_message("https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/957163963588681788/957165926103519282/gc.gif")
        if select.values[0] == "3" and "2":
            await interaction.response.send_message("https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/957163963588681788/957165926103519282/gc.gif")

        if select.values[0] == "2" and "4":
            await interaction.response.send_message("https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/957163963588681788/957166060077981716/gp.gif")
        if select.values[0] == "4" and "2":
            await interaction.response.send_message("https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/957163963588681788/957166060077981716/gp.gif")

        if select.values[0] == "2" and "5":
            await interaction.response.send_message("https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/957163963588681788/957166244820312064/gb.gif")
        if select.values[0] == "5" and "2":
            await interaction.response.send_message("https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/957163963588681788/957166244820312064/gb.gif")

        if select.values[0] == "3" and "4":
            await interaction.response.send_message("https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/957163963588681788/957164839044792320/cp.gif")
        if select.values[0] == "4" and "3":
            await interaction.response.send_message("https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/957163963588681788/957164839044792320/cp.gif")

        if select.values[0] == "3" and "5":
            await interaction.response.send_message("https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/957163963588681788/957167056443305984/cb.gif")
        if select.values[0] == "5" and "3":
            await interaction.response.send_message("https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/957163963588681788/957167056443305984/cb.gif")

        if select.values[0] == "4" and "5":
            await interaction.response.send_message("https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/957163963588681788/957168215568580618/pb.gif")
```